# why objectID(N'tablename') does not lock and name='tablename' does lock on sys.objects?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Experiment details:

I am running this in Microsoft SQL Server management studio.
On one query window I run:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION a; 
      ALTER table <table name> 
            ALTER column <column> varchar(1025)
```

On the other I run:

```
SELECT 1 
       FROM sys.objects 
       WHERE name = ' <other_table name>'
```

Or this:

```
SELECT 1 
       FROM sys.objects 
       WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[<other_table name>]')
```

For some reason the select with name= does not return until I do commit to the tranaction.

I am doing transaction to simulate a long operation of alter column that we have in our DB sometimes. Which I don't want to harm other operations.

Comment: If you look at the actual execution plans for both, you should see that the `name` variant uses a seek on a non-clustered index and a separate lookup step. Whereas the `object_id` variant just performs a clustered index seek. I'd also note that the transaction seems to hold a few exclusive locks on certain keys. I've not managed to construct a complete theory yet (hence comment not answer) but I think it may relate to the first query potentially having to scan ranges (because duplicate `name`s are possible). Unfortunately, `OBJECT_ID` is a black box so not clear why it can work without locks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are working under Default Transaction Isolation Level i.e ReadCommited . 
**Read Commited**
Under Read Commited Trasanction Isolation Level when you explicitly Begin a Transaction Sql Server obtains Exclusive locks on the resources in order to maintain data integrity and prevent users from dirty reads. Once you have begin a transaction and working with some rows other users will not be able to see them rows untill you Commit your transaction or Rollback. However this is sql server's default behaviour this can be changed under different Transaction Isolation Level for instance under Read Uncommited You will be able to read rows which are being Modified/Used by other users , but there is a chance of you have Dirty Reads "Data That you think is still in database but Other user has changed it."
**My Suggestion**
If Dirty Reads is something you can live with go on than

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITED;
```

Preferably Otherwise stick to default behaviour of Sql Server and let the user wait for a bit rather than giving them dirty/wrong data. I hope it helps. 
**Edit**

it does not matter if the both queries are executed under same or different isolation level what matters is under what isolation level the queries are being executed, and you have to have Read Uncommited transaction isolation level when you are making use of explicit transactions. If you want other user to have access to the data in during a transaction. Not recomended and a bad practice, I would personally use Snapshot Isolation which will extensively make use of tempdb and will only show the last commited data.

Comment: But both queries run with the same isolation level, still one of the queries requires me to add READ UNCOMMITED, the other does not. That was the exact question.

Comment: please see my updated answer for further explaination. thankyou

Comment: Please re-read the OPs question. They have 3 pieces of code. Place those three pieces into 3 separate query windows, connected to the same database, and create/adapt appropriate table and column names. Run the first piece. If you switch to the second piece and try running it, it blocks. If you switch to the third piece and try running it, it runs fine. The question is why piece 2 blocks and piece 3 doesn't.